# mongo-hadoop connector:how to query data

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop-streaming

I'm using hadoop mongo connector in java(spark application).I've done reading mongo db by setting this  configuration

```
Configuration mongodbConfig = new Configuration();
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/MyCollectionName.collection");
```

What can I add to query the data (like `.limit(100000)`)

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more parameters in the config
example:

```
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.query", "{'field':'value'}");
```

see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Configuration-Reference
for more details

Comment: limit is set using: mongo.input.limit